# can't get variables from TF collection

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

Aurelion Geron's [example](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/11_deep_learning.ipynb) shows how to stored selected operations in a collection, so they can then be easily accessed later:

Adding:

```
for op in (X, y, accuracy, training_op):
    tf.add_to_collection("my_important_ops", op)
```

Then retrieving:

```
X, y, accuracy, training_op = tf.get_collection("my_important_ops")
```

However when I try to do this I get this error:

```
X, y, accuracy, training_op = tf.get_collection("my_important_ops")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to do the following:

```
temp = tf.get_collection("my_important_ops")
print(temp.get_shape().as_list())
```

Then you can evaluate the outputs.